# Working without internet connection with Google Formulaire

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

I have been looking for in internet and I don't find very much. Actually, I think that is not possible yet. But I would like to see if someone here can confirm me.

I'm working in industrial processes. I am trying to create a tool in google forms for the operators of my company. This "Google form" will be fill out by the operators. When he or she will click "send", this will create automatically a PDF which will be send by email to our client as a report. I am using the add on Document Studio and, despite I am not an expert, this tool is really really interesting and great.

What I would like to improve (and which would allow me to use the full capacity of these two interesting tools), is working without internet connection, because sometimes, in the plateforms, we dont' have a good signal. So it would be great if the technicien could fill out the form without internet connection and somehow save it in local and, once his phone receive signal, the form would be send in an automatique way.

Hope my message is clear :)

Comment: Google Forms require an internet connection [see here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4204405?hl=en) You'll most likely need to host an internal intranet web app on your server to accommodate such a request.

Comment: what you are asking in different analogy is: if you can drive a car without all wheels although you have a full tank

Answer (score -1):

> Google Forms require an internet connection [see
>   here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4204405?hl=en). You'll
>   most likely need to host an internal intranet web app on your server
>   to accommodate such a request.

[Datanovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9375102/datanovice)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm gonna check the third comment...What you are saying seems to be very very complicated for my technical skills in informatic. But thanks for the proposal.